# Excel. Use If Then to increase the value of another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I apologize if something like this has been asked, but I've been through many excel questions and can't find something to cover this.

I have 2 columns. I want to see if one column is less than the other.  If it is, in a third column I want a single cell to gain + 1.  So if twice column A's cells were less than Column B, then column C would show a value of 2, and on.

As a bonus I would like the third column to be on a separate sheet, which I can figure out myself, but I'm sure someone can do it better.

To clarify: If A1 < B1 then C1=C1+1  and If A2 < B2 then C1=C1+1

If they are not less than, nothing should happen.

Comment: Your explanation is very confusing. What do you mean by "one column is less than the other"? Do you mean like the value of two adjacent cells or the sum of all the cells in a column?

Comment: What if A1 > B1?. Besides, you cannot have a circular reference.  Therefore, C1 = C1 + 1 is not allowed.

Comment: Then nothing should happen at all

Comment: So really then it would be best to do something like: =IF(A1<B1,1) and sum the resulting column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am reading this question as "How do I count the total number of values in column A which are less than their corresponding values in column B?"

If that is correct, then you want an array formula in cell C1:

```
=sum(if(A1:A10<B1:b10,1,0))
```

When you type this in, enter with control-shift-enter all at once.  That should make it look like this:

```
={sum(if(A1:A10<B1:b10,1,0))}
```

and should show the total count in cell c1.

Comment: I read the question the same way, but was not sure. Nicely done!

Comment: To make this more complex is there a way to use this to check for specific numbers in that range and then sum this formula.  I.E For each cell B1:B10 that equals 9 use the same formula to find the corresponding cell in A1:A10 and check if it is less than 9.  The corresponding cells are important.

Comment: Does this work?   I am on my phone and can't verify :   ={sum(if(and(A1:A10<B1:b10,b1:b10=9),1,0))}

Comment: With a 9 in B and 8 in A it is returning 0

Comment: I'll figure it out in an hour when I get home.   Definitely possible.

Comment: I really appreciate your assistance

Comment: a1 <> b1 means the cells are not equal. If this is what you want, just edit ADAM's formula and try it.

Comment: We're looking for more than not equal.  Specifically we are taking an overall score.  Lets say its 9.  We then are comparing against sub category scores to see how many people rated a sub category less than their overall score. So we need the numbers to compare directly against their other responses.  The original formula does that well, but we also need to be able to break it into smaller data.  "Of the 300 people who gave us a 10, 65 of them gave lighting a score lower than 10."

Comment: Here we go:  `=SUM(IF(B1:B5=9,IF(A1:A5<B1:B5,1,0),0))`  as an array formula will achieve the desired result.  You could of course replace the "9" with a cell reference to make a table (e.g. have c1=9, then put `=SUM(IF(B1:B5=c1,IF(A1:A5<B1:B5,1,0),0))` in c2.

Answer (score 1):

To reference cells in different sheets:  sheet name followed by '!' followed by cell. For example" =Sheet1!A1

Circular references are not allowed in Excel formulas.  However, you can use a macro to do so.  The following macro adds one to cell C1 if the values of A1 and B1 are not equal

```
Sub addOneToCell()
val1 = Range("A1").Value
val2 = Range("B1").Value
val3 = Range("C1").Value

If val1 <> val2 Then Range("C1").Value = val3 + 1

End Sub
```

**UPDATE**:

This is the same as above, but iterating through cells.  **WARNING** as I expected, it is VERY slow:

```
Sub addOneToCell()

For i = 1 To Rows.Count

    If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1).Value) And Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2).Value) And Cells(i, 1).Value <> Cells(i, 2) Then Range("C1").Value = Range("C1").Value + 1

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: This is excellent as well.  Is there a way to make this continue through the whole sheet?  There are over 700 cells in each column.

Comment: My knowledge of VB and Excel macros is very limited.  I am sure there is a way, I just don't know how.  I think the solution by ADAM and Jason Aller is your best option to be honest.  I think executing a Excel formula is way faster than running a VB macro in Excel.

Comment: Thank you for this as well.  Both solutions are useful to me in several ways and you have given me a good starting point!

Answer (score 0):

There may be better ways, but I would start like this.

1. Give formula for first row of `=if(a1<b1,1,0)`
2. Give formula for second row of `=c1+if(a2<b2,1,0)`
3. Fill second row down through your data set

Comment: I think your first formula should be `=if(a1<>b1,1,0)`. The statement was "if **one column** is less than the other", not "if **column one** is less than the other".  One column bigger than the other means the values are not equal.

Comment: I can see both interpretations, but i think my answer meets his requirements based on his edits. Fortunately it is easy to fix based on his real requirements